# Is an entry permit required to travel to Hong Kong with a Chinese passport but no hukou in China?

Tags: hong-kong, chinese-citizens, entry-permit

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_policy_of_Hong_Kong#Mainland_China,_Macau_and_Taiwan):

> Chinese nationals with hukou in Mainland China are required to obtain an entry permit from the Public Security Bureau for any type of visit to Hong Kong (Two-way Permit required for short visits and long visits, or One-way Permit for settlement), as well as an entry endorsement (similar to a visa) for the purpose of travel. The duration of stay is usually 7 days per trip.

The thing is, my main residence isn't in China. Thus, my passport was issued by a Consulate general in a foreign country with no hukou in Mainland China.

> [hukou](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hukou_system) is a system of household registration in mainland China. A household registration record officially identifies a person as a resident of an area and includes identifying information such as name, parents, spouse, and date of birth.

*Question 1:* **Do I also require an entry permit like Chinese nationals with hukou in Mainland China?**

Additionally, I am currently on vacation in Mainland China, which means that I would travel to Hong Kong from Mainland China.

*Question 2:* **Does this affect the answer to** *Question 1* **and if so, how?**

Edit: For the sake of clarification in case someone wants to denounce this question as multiple questions, which should be avoided to answer according to the [Answering Help Page](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).

The main question to be answered should be *Question 2* taking into consideration all information.

But if me not traveling from Mainland China would provide an alternative with no requirement of an entry permit, the answer to *Question 1* could be included as well.

Comment: @HankyPanky I am sorry I didn't include that. Here you go.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, as an overseas Chinese resident you will need an entry permit to visit Hong Kong.

As per the Hong Kong Immigration Department's [Arrangements for Entry to the Hong Kong Special Administrative Region (HKSAR) for Overseas Chinese and Chinese residents of Taiwan](https://www.immd.gov.hk/eng/services/visas/overseas-chinese-entry-arrangement.html):

> 2. PRC passport holders living overseas wishing to enter Hong Kong for visit, employment, training, study or residence should apply for an appropriate entry permit

That page contains further information on how to apply.